# Where do I find list of breaking changes for Any NodeJS version

Tags: node.js, version, release

I am currently using node 6.1 in my project.
I want to upgrade it to latest stable version now.
Before doing that I want to know what are the breaking changes introduced in all the versions in between 6 to 12

Is there any place I can get all these breaking changes for the node versions.

Answer (score 13):

I've found this page to be the most helpful list of all major/minor/patch changes:

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v16.0.0/

Answer (score 5):

Another good resource to find changes to all the different major versions, is the changelog archive on nodejs' github:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/main/doc/changelogs